# Opencart - How to get module settings at front-end

Tags: module, opencart

For example, I have a ABC_module, which are available in two layout, each module has an extra setting field: 'Category ID'.

- common/home with position = 'Content Top', Category ID = 5
- product/category with position = 'Content Left', Category ID = 4

Now I want to get the value of 'Category ID' setting in my front-end module controller.
So I can choose which Category to display to the user.

Can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: The answer is pass a argument to index() function in module controller. For example: public index($setting) {...}. After viewing slideshow module controller, I can understand this.

Comment: There is a model called setting I believe, module settings are stored in a settings table in the database and this is used to interface with them.

Answer (score 2):

The same way as non-admin config:

```
$this->config->get('key_that_you_need');
```

All data saved in table settings, look there the key name of setting you need and fetch it.